# Running Elastic Search with Laradock

Tags: laravel, docker, elasticsearch, laradock

I'm trying to get ElasticSearch running with Laradock. ES looks to be supported out of the box with Laradock.

Here's my docker command (run from `<project root>/laradock/`:

`docker-compose up -d nginx postgres redis beanstalkd elasticsearch`

However if I run `docker ps`, the elasticsearch container isn't running.

Both ports `9200` and `9300` are not consumed:

`lsof -i :9200`

Not sure why the elasticsearch container doesn't persist, it seems to just self close.

output of `docker ps -a` after running `docker-compose up ...`

http://pastebin.com/raw/ymfvLPLT

Condensed version:

```
IMAGE                     STATUS                        PORTS
laradock_nginx            Up 36 seconds                 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp
laradock_elasticsearch    Exited (137) 34 seconds ago
laradock_beanstalkd       Up 37 seconds                 0.0.0.0:11300->11300/tcp
laradock_php-fpm          Up 38 seconds                 9000/tcp
laradock_workspace        Up 39 seconds                 0.0.0.0:2222->22/tcp
tianon/true               Excited (0) 41 seconds ago
laradock_postgres         Up 41 seconds                 0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp
laradock_redis            Up 40 seconds                 0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp
```

Output of `docker events` after running `docker-compose up ...`

http://pastebin.com/cE9bjs6i

Comment: post `docker ps -a` and `docker events` it should say some things

Comment: @user2915097 i've added the extra info

Comment: the question is outdated elasticsearch works out of the box with latest Laradock

Answer (score 2):

Run on laradock file the command

```
wsl -d docker-desktop 
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-cli-run-prod-mode

Answer (score 1):

Try to check logs first:

```
docker logs laradock_elasticsearch_1
```

(or another name of elasticsearch container)

In my case it was

```
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
```

I found solution [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-docker/issues/92#issuecomment-323132686)
namely, i've run on my Ubuntu machine

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is related to Laradock, since Elasticsearch is supposed to be running on it's own, I would first check the memory:

- open Docker Dashboard -> Settings -> Resources -> Advanced: and increase the memory.
- check your Machine memory, Elasticsearch won't run if there is not enough memory in your machine.
- or:

  - open your docker-compose.yml file
  - increase the mem_limit: 1g then
  - docker-compose up -d --build elasticsearch

If it's still not working, remove all the images, update laradock to latest version and setup it new.